# Spark: restart counting on specific value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataFrame with Boolean records and i want restart the counting when goal=False/Null.

How can i get the Score tab ? 
The score tab is a count of True values with a reset on False/null values

My df:

```
Goals
Null 
True
False 
True
True
True
True
False 
False 
True
True
```

Expected Result:

```
Goals   Score
Null    0
True    1
False   0
True    1
True    2
True    3
True    4
False   0
False   0
True    1
True    2
```

EDIT: Adding more infos

Actually my full dataset is:

```
Player   Goals         Date         Score
1       Null    2017-08-18 10:30:00 0
1       True    2017-08-18 11:30:00 1
1       False   2017-08-18 12:30:00 0
1       True    2017-08-18 13:30:00 1
1       True    2017-08-18 14:30:00 2
1       True    2017-08-18 15:30:00 3
1       True    2017-08-18 16:30:00 4
1       False   2017-08-18 17:30:00 0
1       False   2017-08-18 18:30:00 0
1       True    2017-08-18 19:30:00 1
1       True    2017-08-18 20:30:00 2
2       False   2017-08-18 10:30:00 0
2       False   2017-08-18 11:30:00 0
2       True    2017-08-18 12:30:00 1
2       True    2017-08-18 13:30:00 2
2       False   2017-08-18 15:30:00 0
```

I've created a window to calculate the score by player on a certain date

```
   val w = Window.partitionBy("Player","Goals").orderBy("date")
```

I've tried with the lag function and comparing the values but i can't reset the count.

EDIT2: Add unique Date per player

Thank you.

Comment: how is spark supposed to know how your data is ordered?

Comment: That's why my first attempt was with an ordered dataFrame

Comment: so player 1 scored 7 goals on one day?

Comment: Yes the total without the reset condition is 7.

Comment: date and player combinations are still not unique so we can't guarantee that your data will be ordered as you wish.

Comment: I can get the unix epoch related to each action. So the combination (Player/date) will be unique.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question.

Comment: @eliasah: How can i get the Score tab. 
The score tab is a count of True values with a reset on False/null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem with grouping the goals that occurs together.

I used a count over a partition containing the difference between the row index of the "table" and the row_number related to the partitioned window.

First declare the window with future columns to use

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("player","goals","countPartition").orderBy("date")
```

Then populate the columns "countPartition" and "goals" with 1 to keep the rowNumber neutral

```
  val list1=  dataList.withColumn("countPartition", lit(1)).withColumn("goals", lit(1)).withColumn("index", rowNumber over w )
```

the udf

```
def div = udf((countInit: Int, countP: Int) => countInit-countP)
```

And finally calculate the score

```
  val score = list1.withColumn("goals", goals).withColumn("countPartition", div(col("index") , rowNumber over w )).withColumn("Score", when(col("goals") === true, count("goals") over w ).otherwise(when(col("goals") isNull, "null").otherwise(0))).orderBy("date")
```